# React `componentDidCatch` not being called but required to handle error?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cordova

I'm trying to use React's `componentDidCatch` method to catch an error that's causing a crash in my Cordova iOS app. It appears to be preventing the crash, but the method never gets called, so I have no idea what is causing the problem.

My component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { View, observable } from 'shared/View';
import { Player } from 'video-react';
import SpinnerOverlay from 'shared/components/SpinnerOverlay';
import * as Icons from 'shared/components/Icons';
import fs from 'fileSystem';

export default class VideoOverlay extends View {
  @observable ready = false;

  handlePlayerStateChange = (state, prevState) => {
    const { onClose } = this.props;

    if(state.paused && !prevState.paused && onClose) {
      try {
        onClose();
      } catch(error) {
        console.log('--- onClose error', error);
      }
    }
  };

  handlePlayerRef = (player) => {
    player.subscribeToStateChange(this.handlePlayerStateChange);
    player.play();
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const { mediaFile } = this.props;
      await mediaFile.download(fs);
      this.ready = true;
    } catch(error) {
      console.log('--- SHIT', error);
    }
  }

  componentDidCatch(error) {
    // Needed because `Player` throws an error when unmounting.
    // This method doesn't get called (not sure why), but without this method,
    // the app crashes when a video is closed.
    console.log('Caught', error);
  }

  render() {
    const { ready } = this;
    const { mediaFile } = this.props;
    const src = ready && mediaFile.fileSrc;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <SpinnerOverlay visible/>
        {ready &&
          <Player ref={this.handlePlayerRef}>
            <source src={src}/>
          </Player>
        }
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The component works fine except when it unmounts, it consistently throws this error:

```
2018-02-22 12:52:19.706530-0800 App[1094:598984] ERROR: The above error occurred in the <Player> component:
    in Player (created by Component)
    in Component (created by Component)
    in div (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by Component)
    in Component (created by inject-Component-with-store)
    in inject-Component-with-store (created by Route)
    in Route (created by Component)
    in Switch (created by Component)
    in Component (created by inject-Component-with-store)
    in inject-Component-with-store (created by Route)
    in Route (created by Component)
    in Component (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Component))
    in withRouter(Component) (created by inject-withRouter(Component)-with-api)
    in inject-withRouter(Component)-with-api (created by Component)
    in Switch (created by Component)
    in div (created by App__Root)
    in App__Root (created by Component)
    in Component (created by Route)
    in Route (created by withRouter(Component))
    in withRouter(Component)
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter
    in Provider
```

This error appears in the XCode console with no error above it. The `console.log` in `componentDidCatch` never runs. The `catch` blocks in `componentDidMount` and `handlePlayerStateChange` are also never reached.

The strangest thing about this is if I remove `componentDidCatch`, the app crashes with the above error, so `componentDidCatch` appears to be doing *something*; it's just not letting me actually handle the error.

Also, I can't reproduce this issue in a browser because this component only works in iOS (this component takes advantage of iOS's automatic fullscreening of autoplayed videos).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is `componentDidCatch` doesn't catch event handler errors, like the ones that would occur with the handler inside your `handlePlayerRef` method. And that's because these types of errors don't occur during the rendering of a component, which is the intended purpose of `didCatch`.

For example, this would not be properly caught and logged by `didCatch`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentDidCatch() {
    console.log('whats wrong?')
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    //errors emerging here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Click</button>
    );
  }
}
```

If you need to catch these sorts of errors, use the conventional try/catch blocks inside your `handlePlayerRef`.

```
handlerPlayerRef() {
  try {
    player.subscribeToStateChange(this.handlePlayerStateChange);
    player.play();
  } catch () {
    console.error('Something wrong happened');
  }
}
```

Also, it's usually best to decouple component rendering errors from your components functionality because it tends to generate cryptic errors that are hard to debug.

Have you tried building an ErrorBoundary component to wrap over your VideoOverlay class? Do that and condition the rendering of it to the non-existence of errors:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  componentDidCatch(err) {
    this.setState({
      hasError: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.hasError 
      ?  <h2>Oh noes! Something went wrong.</h2>
      :  this.props.children
   }
}
```

Now you can just provide VideoOverlay as a child of ErrorBoundary:

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <VideoOverlay />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

Read in more detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)